# Elegant way to toggle back and force multiple css elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 buttons with ids "videos-button" and "photos-button". On click of each button, I need to perform a set of action to changes css or remove/add class for certain HTML elements. Basically, for each of the element, I need to toggle their initial state back and force. See code for details:

```
$('#videos-button').on('click',function(){
            $("#ib-row").css({'display':'none'});
            $("#ib-pagination").css({'display':'none'});
            $("#ib-video-carousel-pagination").css({'display':'block'});
            $("#ib-video-carousel").css({'display':'block'});
            $("#photos-button").removeClass('image-block-media-button-selected');
            $("#videos-button").addClass('image-block-media-button-selected');
});


$('#photos-button').on('click',function(){
            $("#ib-row").css({'display':'block'});
            $("#ib-pagination").css({'display':'block'});
            $("#ib-video-carousel-pagination").css({'display':'none'});
            $("#ib-video-carousel").css({'display':'none'});
            $("#videos-button").removeClass('image-block-media-button-selected');
            $("#photos-button").addClass('image-block-media-button-selected');
        });
```

How can I refactor it in more elegant way, without duplication?

Comment: For all of those elements which have their CSS set, are there any other possibilities other than the combinations shown in those two handlers? For example, if `#ib-row` has `display: block`, will `#ib-pagination` always have `display: block`, and `#ib-video-carousel` have `display: none`, and `#photos-button` have the selected class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to refactor would be, create a function which takes videos-button or photos-button as input and returns a object(map) of ids and corresponding classes. i.e function(lets call it **getClassMap**) returning

```
{ '#id-row' : 'display: none', ... }
```

when i/p is videos-button and

```
{ '#id-row' : 'display: block', ... }
```

when i/p is photos-button.
Then move the logic of applying classes i.e

```
function applyStyles(id) {
    const styleIdMap = getClassMap(id);
    $("#ib-row").css(styleIdMap["#ib-row"]);
    $("#ib-pagination").css(styleIdMap["#ib-pagination"]);
    ...
}
```

this way there is no repition in logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
const ibRowAndPagination = ['#ib-row', '#ib-pagination'];
const ibVideoCarouselAndPagination = ['#ib-video-carousel-pagination', '#ib-video-carousel'];
const photosAndVideosButtons = ['#photos-button', '#videos-button'];
const photosAndVideosButtonsToggleClass = () => photosAndVideosButtons.forEach(el => $(el).toggleClass('image-block-media-button-selected'));

$('#videos-button').on('click', function() {
  ibRowAndPagination.forEach(el => $(el).css({'display':'none'}));
  ibVideoCarouselAndPagination.forEach(el => $(el).css({'display':'block'}));
  photosAndVideosButtonsToggleClass();
});

$('#photos-button').on('click', function() {
  ibRowAndPagination.forEach(el => $(el).css({'display':'block'}));
  ibVideoCarouselAndPagination.forEach(el => $(el).css({'display':'none'}));
  photosAndVideosButtonsToggleClass();
});
```